# iOS native app automation using appium

Tags: ios, automation, ios-simulator, appium

I recently started working on iOS native app automation -

MAC OS 10.10.2 
iOS simulator - iPhone 5s, iOS 8.1
Appium 1.3.4

App is in App store - I am using the .app file of this app store app

iOS settings in Appium.app -
App path - gave path to .app file
Force device - simulator device

Code -

```
    DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();


capabilities.setCapability("deviceName", "iPhone 5s");

capabilities.setCapability("platformName", "iOS");

  driver = new IOSDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"),capabilities);
```

I also tried giving the app path onle in code but not in appium.app, I tried running with and without the bundle id of the app

But none of this works, I am not able to install the app in the simulator.

With the settings and code mentioned above I always get - Appium session could not be started. Instruments crashed

And when I give the bundle id of the app I get error as - A new session could not be created. (Original error: ENOENT, no such file or directory '/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/com.nbcuni.syfy.syfychannel/Info.plist')

Can someone please help me out?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
capabilities.setCapability("platformName", "....");
capabilities.setCapability("deviceName", "....");
capabilities.setCapability("platformVersion", "...");
capabilities.setCapability("appPackage", "....");
capabilities.setCapability("appActivity", "...");
```

Answer (score 0):

You should include "app" setting into your capabilities. It points to your .app or .ipa file.
Also, if you want to be 100% sure that instruments are working run them directly: `instruments -w "iPhone 5s" -t "Automation" ~/My.app -e UIASCRIPT my_script.js` my_script.js could be just empty.